# How to disable this AndroidStudio source code display feature?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

AndroidStudio has this source code display feature enabled by default that i find extremely distracting. It "compacts" source code by altering it's appearance. Original source code is displayed on mouse-over or expands on click. Screenshot below displays "enhanced" code and original code in a tooltip when mouse is hovered over the original code.

[image: sample]

Do you know how this feature is called and how could i disable it? I spent too long already going through all IDE settings unable to find it and get rid of it.

Comment: Could you please share idea.log ("Help | Show log in...") after restarting  IDE?

Comment: This is the log: https://gist.github.com/c5be482fe6afcfadbe740fcf4fd5f266

Comment: This feature is provided by "Advanced Java Folding". You could disable it or configure folding options in "Settings | Editor | General | Code Folding"

Comment: Thank you very much! You should post this as an answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is provided by "Advanced Java Folding". You could disable it or configure folding options in "Settings | Editor | General | Code Folding"